# Central Authentication Service Jasig for Wordpress and Spring MVC(REST) application

Tags: spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas, jasig

I have an application which is completely written in Java with Spring framework. Right now I need to integrate this application with some other application that is written on WordPress. Both applications have their own user database.

I need to implement Single Sign-on for both of these applications.  I'm looking to CAS [Jasig](http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.1.x/index.html) for this purpose(for example for WP I have found following plugin [CAS Maestro](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cas-maestro/)).

Right now, I don't understand where users for WP and Spring MVC applications must be stored in order to pass authentication via Jasig CAS? I mean is it a single store(for example the same mysql database) or it can(must) be a different stores for each application ? Or Jasig CAS will have own users database and WP and Spring MVC application will also create the same users in own databases after successful authentication by CAS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've made WP Cassify. This is a WordPress CAS Authentication plugin compatible with the latest CAS Server Version.
Plugin hosted on Wordpress.org : https://fr.WordPress.org/plugins/wp-cassify/
The Online documentation : https://wpcassify.wordPress.com/

Best regards